# how do i make a updating inventory in discord.py (like what items are users getting) in python

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making a discord bot. So can you guys help me to make a automatically updating inventory which can show what items are users getting. And I am also sharing the source code which was officially made in repl.it ( an online editor for python ). I am sharing the source code, so you guys can understand the format. -

[my code]-

Comment: code -   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJbTX.png

Comment: Welcome to SO! We can better help you if you paste your code as text inside your question rather than in an image. See the styling guide for more:  https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. Also please share what is not working, and what you've tried so the question is more specific.